# Plotting Results from For Iteration

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I am new to `python` and I want to ask how to plot a figure from `for` loop iteration?

Here is the code!

```
import numpy as np #numerical python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt #python plotting
from math import exp #exponential math directory
T_initial = 293
T_reference = range(298,340,2)
R1_initial = 57500
R2_initial = 13300
R3_initial = 18000
R4_initial = 5600
Beta = 4150
Vin = 2.8
for i in T_reference:
    R1_refe = R1_initial*exp(Beta*((1/i)-(1/T_initial)))
    Rs = (R2_initial/(R2_initial+ R1_refe)) - (R4_initial/(R3_initial+R4_initial))
    Vo = Vin*Rs
    Vo_round = round(Vo, 3)
    print(i,Vo_round)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can plot the data like this:

```
for i in T_reference:
    R1_refe = R1_initial*exp(Beta*((1/i)-(1/T_initial)))
    Rs = (R2_initial/(R2_initial+ R1_refe)) - (R4_initial/(R3_initial+R4_initial))
    Vo = Vin*Rs
    Vo_round = round(Vo, 3)
    plt.scatter(i, Vo_round)
plt.show()
```

Is this what you were looking for?

[image]

Comment: thank you very much sir. Its really help me for my code. Yeah sure this is what i looking for

Answer (score 0):

1. Put the values of the items you want to plot into two different arrays using the 'append' method (one for the 'x' axis and one for the 'y' axis).
2. Then just plot the graph with the matplotlib
3. It should be something like the below:

```py
is1 = list()
vos = list()

for i in T_reference:
    R1_refe = R1_initial*exp(Beta*((1/i)-(1/T_initial)))
    Rs = (R2_initial/(R2_initial+ R1_refe)) - (R4_initial/(R3_initial+R4_initial))
    Vo = Vin*Rs
    Vo_round = round(Vo, 3)
    print(i,Vo_round)
    is1.append(i)
    vos.append(Vo_round)

plt.plot(is1,vos)
```

[Here is a reference for plotting](https://swcarpentry.github.io/python-novice-gapminder/09-plotting/)

Answer (score 0):

## Two options without a `for-loop`

### Create a function

```py
def v_o(T_reference):
    T_initial = 293
    R1_initial = 57500
    R2_initial = 13300
    R3_initial = 18000
    R4_initial = 5600
    Beta = 4150
    Vin = 2.8

    R1_refe = R1_initial*exp(Beta*((1/T_reference)-(1/T_initial)))
    Rs = (R2_initial/(R2_initial + R1_refe)) - (R4_initial/(R3_initial+R4_initial))
    Vo = Vin*Rs
    Vo_round = round(Vo, 3)
    return Vo_round
```

### Option 1: Use a `pandas` dataframe

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create the dataframe with T_reference
df = pd.DataFrame({'t_ref': [*range(298, 340,2)]})

# Call the function to calculate v_o
df['v_o'] = df.t_ref.apply(v_o)

# plot
df.plot('t_ref', 'v_o', legend=False)
plt.show()
```

### Option 2: use `map`

```py
T_reference = [*range(298, 340,2)]
v_o = list(map(v_o, T_reference))

plt.plot(T_reference, v_o)
plt.show()
```

#### Plot

- The plot from both options looks like the following

[image]